# UE4のクロスコンパイルにおける静的ライブラリと動的ライブラリについて

Tags: c++, linux, windows

UnrealEngine4でクロスコンパイルする時に静的ライブラリと動的ライブラリはどのOS用にすれば良いですか？
例えばWindowsでLinuxをターゲットにするとします．
この時必要な静的ライブラリと動的ライブラリはどちらのOSですか？
具体的にはパッケージ化を行います．
予め御礼申し上げます.

Answer (score 0):

一般論になりますが、Windows向けのライブラリは`.lib`や`.dll`、Linux向けのライブラリは`.a`や`.so`という拡張子を持っており、フォーマットもそれぞれ異なります（PEとELF）。したがって、ライブラリは両方のOSについてそれぞれ必要です。macOSもまた別に`.dylib`（Mach-O）を使います。